# FileDescriptor.sync() thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, file-descriptor

Wondering about the following scenario (simplified Java code):

```
//Thread A:

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH);
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
BufferedWriter buffW = new BufferedWriter(osw, SIZE);

for (int i = 0; i < ITER; i++) {
    buffW.write(STR);
}

//Thread B:

fos.getFD().sync();
```

Is there a need to synchronize the `sync()` call w/ the other write, or does this get taken care of at OS-level? My gut feeling says that this should be the OS's concern, but I could be wrong.

The docs do not touch on this subject, I get only a hint that there's some synchronization going on for `FileChannel.force(...)`, which should be equivalent, but the scenario in the docs seems somewhat different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be thread safe, since file descriptors are managed by the OS. It seems like a rather strange thing to want to do, though.

Comment: I admit, it is. I have some writer tasks that are logging some info in log files. However, there's another thread that, asynchronously, can initiate an upload of said logs. Since I cannot stop the logging process during the upload (time constraints), plus I've had instances where the OS caching prevented the data from actually landing on the disk (so that my upload was missing critical info), I want to flush the OS buffers as soon as an upload is initiated. This way, I'll always have a correct snapshot ready for upload, up to that moment.

Comment: This sounds like a job for The Actor Model! :-)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that (what I suppose to be) pattern, maybe it fits better than my current approach.